# How to get code suggestions for structs using Solidity, VSCode and hardhat?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity

I am developing some smart contracts using Solidity, hardhat and VSCode with [this extension](https://github.com/juanfranblanco/vscode-solidity).

The code suggestions work fine when I'm using imported contracts, but not when using structs:

FooContract.sol:

```
import "./BooStruct.sol";
import "./BarContract.sol";

contract FooContract {
  // Staring to type "Bar" here already gives me the suggestion for "BarContract"
  BarContract bar;
  
  // Typing "Boo" here gives me no suggestions
  BooStruct boo;
  constructor(BarContract _bar, string memory _name) {
    bar = _bar;
    boo = BooStruct(_name);
  }

  function foo() public {
    bar. // gives me suggestions for both functions I have on BarContract
    string memory name = boo. // gives me no code suggestions
  }
}
```

BarContract.sol:

```
contract BarContract {
  function bar() public pure returns(string memory) {
    return "bar";
  }

  function beeh() public pure returns(string memory) {
    return "beeh";
  }
}
```

BooStruct.sol:

```
struct BooStruct {
  string name;
}
```

How can I get the code suggestions to work for the structs as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct BooStruct {
  string name;
}
```

please insert the variable into FooContract.